# Finding the phase shift of a cosine function, given the graph

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, graphing-functions

[image]

Here is what I have found so far:

Vertical Displacement = 2 units down (-2)

Amplitude = 4

Period = 2pi/3

I am now trying to find the phase shift. I moved the 'working x-axis' 2 units down, in accordance with the vertical displacement of -2. Since the cosine function starts at 1 on the y-axis, how do I find the phase shift. If the x-axis is at -2, then the point where y=1 is a tiny fraction of a unit away from the y-axis. So how do I find the phase shift?

Comment: Note that the simple cosine graph intersects the y-axis at (0,1).

Comment: Noted. @Pakquebchsoflwty When my x-axis is at -2, y=1 (relative to the working axis) is very close to (0,1). How do I determine the phase shift from there?

Comment: You are not looking for where y=1.  You are looking for where $y=1\times 4 - 2$  You need to take into account the amplitude and vertical shift of the function.  So, where does y=2 that will give you the least possible shift?

Comment: Of course, thanks for making that more clear. So y=2 when we move the graph 1 unit left, in other words the phase shift will be +1?

Comment: Actually, -1.  The phase shift is the opposite of what many people intuitively think.  I always think of it like this. Cosine is a maximum at $\cos{(0)}$ So in this case, we want a maximum at y=1, so $\cos{(x-1)}$ fits the bill.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. Thanks for your help.

Comment: well yeah 1 unit. but what are the units here guys? pi/6. so it's pi/6 shift. not 1!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple function $4\cos(x)$ will have a relative maximum at $(0,4)$.
However, your function seems to be $4\cos(x-1)-2$. The phase shift I believe is $\frac{\omega}{\phi}$. In this case, $\omega = 1$ and $\phi=1$. So the phase shift is $\frac{1}{1}=1$.